# Record Screen's Happenings(Audio+Video)

Tags: node.js, webrtc

i am new baby in WebRTC and want to implement system like video conferencing , live streaming or you can skype using WebRTC and NodeJS. 
i am confused with one thing , as its our one of client's requirement , suppose on page whatever is happening it may be video conferencing say one moderator answering to many audiences one by one , so there should be one video created , which continuously recording all this stuff together and sending live stream to server to save in our database.
is this kind of stuff implementable or not?
any help please.

Comment: yes, you can grab screen images and send them over websockets, you can do the same with the audio. What specifically do you question about it?

Comment: @bwtrent: any reference please?

Answer (score 0):

You can capture video through grabbing Jpeg images from a canvas element. You could also capture the entire page(if numerous videos in the same page) through grabbing the page itself through chrome.

For audio, [recording remote audio](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/demos/remote-stream-recording.html) with the Audio API is still an issue but locally grabbed audio is not an issue.

- [RecordRTC](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/) and my [Modified Version](https://github.com/Computician/WebSocketWebRTCRecorders) for recording streams either to file or through websockets respectively.
- [Capture a page to a stream](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/Chrome-Extensions/desktopCapture) on how to record or screenShare an entire page of Chrome.

If you have multiple different videos not all in the same page but want to combine them all, I would suggest recording them as above and then combining and syncing them up server side(not in javascript but probably in C or C++).

If you MUST record remote audio, then I would suggest that you have those particular pages send their audio data over websockets themselves so that you can sync them up with their video and with the other sessions.